# Flutter: How to add button under text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put a button under my text.
but I don't know how can I do it. And I encounter this error.
It said that 'the argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified' I don't know how to fix the error.

```
            body: Container(
                
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.amberAccent, Colors.red]
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Welcome', style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 50.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white)
                ),
              ),
             child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text('Button'),)
          ),
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Column`

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("Welcome"),
    RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Button")),
  ],
);
```

---

Full solution:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        colors: [Colors.amberAccent, Colors.red]
    ),
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: Column( // add Column
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Welcome', style: TextStyle( // your text
            fontSize: 50.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white)
        ),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Button'),), // your button beneath text
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: but there is a problem when i run the app. it is not in the center anymore. instead it is on the top literally

Comment: i encounter a error ' mainAxisAlignment isn't defined '

Comment: I am using phone so by mistake I added it to the centre instead of column. Pleas check update b

Comment: Thank you so much bro. is there any advice how can i design a button? design i mean like change it size, color, make round something like that. :)

Comment: Yes of course you can do that. Use shape property in RaisedButton. I am currently out and using mobile, so can't help much as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RaisedButton, it's deprecated. Here is a code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle style =
        ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Push the button',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: style,
              onPressed: null,
              child: const Text('Start'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```